# How to return object property from list

Tags: c#

I have a list of objects with properties:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

my list is:

```
List<CategoriesList> Categories { get; set; }
```

How can I write method that will return object Name with Id that I pass in parameter. How can I return this?

Something like

```
return Categories.Select(x => x.Id == id).Name
```

but it don't make sense.

Comment: Something like return Categories.Select(x => x.Id == id).Name but it don't make sense.

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @user3852834 you're almost there. When you run a `Select` you get a collection. Try selecting the First record ;)

Comment: @user3852834 always have a look at the type of the return value - as ben already said: you will get a collection of categorieslist. thats because LINQ does not know that Id is "unique" for you, e.g. there could be more items with the same Id, or let's say with the same name - that's why you will get a collection when running select.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one:

```
return Categories.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x=>x.Name);
```

As you see from the above you filter the categories based on the id you have and then you select the `Name`.

However, since I assume that `Categories` are unique, you could try also this:

```
// Get the category with the given id. If there is not such a category then the method
// SingleOrDefault returns null.
var category = Categories.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

// Check if the category has been found and return it's Name. 
// Otherwise return an empty string.
return category != null ? category.Name : string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
CategoriesList list = Categories.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);

return (list != null) ? list.Name : null;
```

Comment: @user3852834: Need more help?